# Laravel Mix Webpack compile all except img folder

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, webpack, laravel-mix

I have 
resources/assets/less
resources/assets/js
resources/assets/fonts
resources/assets/img
folders they are all compiled in public expect IMG folder

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the copy method of Mix;

```
mix.copy('resources/assets/img ', 'public/img');
```

See the documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mix#copying-files-and-directories)

Comment: Thank you for response. But it will copy all images without save directories hierarchy
btw once webpac was compiled img folder, but no I don't know what happened